# Слияние столбцов в соответствии с правилом (sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| Буква | Номер1 | Номер2 |
+-------+--------+--------+
|   А   |   1    |   1    |
|   B   |   1    |  NULL  |
|   C   |   2    |   3    |
|   D   |   2    |  NULL  |
|   E   |   3    |   4    |
|   F   |  NULL  |   1    |
|   G   |  NULL  |   2    |
|   H   |  NULL  |   3    |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

Нужно привести её к виду

```
+-------+--------+
| Буква | Номер  |
+-------+--------+
|   А   |   1    |
|   B   |   1    |
|   C   |   2    |
|   D   |   2    |
|   E   |   3    |
|   F   |   1    |
|   G   |   4    |
|   H   |   2    |
+-------+--------+
```

То есть по правилу:

- Если (Номер1 != NULL) И (Номер2 != NULL) - берем Номер1
- Если (Номер1 != NULL) И (Номер2 == NULL) - берем Номер1
- Если (Номер1 == NULL) И (Номер2 != NULL) и существует пара (Номер1* != NULL) И (Номер2* != NULL), где Номер2 == Номер2*, то берем Номер1*
- Если (Номер1 == NULL) И (Номер2 != NULL) и **НЕ** существует пара (Номер1* != NULL) И (Номер2* != NULL), где Номер2 == Номер2*, то берем **НОВЫЙ** номер, которого нет среди Номер1

Без учёта последних двух пунктов всё довольно легко

```
SELECT Буква, ISNULL(Номер1, Номер2) 
FROM Таблица
```

А вот с их учетом - не совсем понятно. То есть беда с последними тремя строками из примера. Более наглядно рассмотрел на примере строки с буквой H:

[image: Пример обработки по третьему пункту]

И буквой G

[image: Пример обработки по четвертому пункту]

Comment: "Если (Номер1 == NULL) И (Номер2 != NULL) и НЕ существует пара (Номер1* != NULL) И (Номер2* != NULL), где Номер2 == Номер2*, то берем НОВЫЙ номер, которого нет среди Номер1" - если таких строк несколько, то все присваеваемые номера должны быть разными?

Comment: Если бы было в примере еще строка [ I - Null - 2 ], то в итоговой таблице она была бы тоже 4, как и G. Но если бы была строка [ J - Null - 7 ], то она бы получила номер 5, т.к. нужной пары не нашлось, то находим опять максимум (предполагая, что 4 уже добавили).

Comment: Третье условие: `SELECT  t.id, ISNULL(t.n1, t2.n1) FROM #test t
LEFT JOIN #test t2 ON t.n2=t2.n2 AND t2.n1 IS not NULL`

Comment: Да, это работает (не знаю насчет производительности, но в лоб - точно работает=). Но как же добить четвертый пункт? Можно дважды наложить проверку на нулл, но что-то надо вписать вместо нуля во внешней проверке: 
SELECT t.id, ISNULL(ISNULL(t.n1, t2.n1),0) FROM #test t LEFT JOIN #test t2 ON t.n2=t2.n2 AND t2.n1 IS not NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая часть - условия 1,2,3. Вторая - условие 4.

```
SELECT t.id, ISNULL(t.n1, t2.n1) FROM #test t 
LEFT JOIN #test t2 ON t.n2=t2.n2 AND t2.n1 IS not NULL
WHERE ISNULL(t.n1, t2.n1) IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.n2)+(SELECT MAX(n1) FROM #test) FROM #test t
LEFT JOIN #test t2 ON t.n2=t2.n2 AND t2.n1 IS not NULL
WHERE ISNULL(t.n1, t2.n1) IS NULL
```

[фиддл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7bb14/2)

Comment: Привет! Почти работает кроме одного момента. Если у нас была бы еще строка [ J - Null - 2 ], то есть не только буква G имеет пару (нул - 2), но и буква J. Мы видим, что они имеют одинаковый номер. Но после выполнения они получат разные номера (4 и 5), а должны одинаковый (4).

Comment: Пропуски в номерах критичны?

Comment: Нет, не думаю. В конце обработки все-равно заново переиндексировать можно будет (по порядку). Главное чтобы у одинаковой группы из второй таблицы после переноса тоже был одинаковый номер.

Comment: Подумал. что там можно будет без пропусков: используем `RANK()` по `n2` вместо `ROW_NUMBER()` - и записи с одинаковым `n2` будут иметь одинаковый индекс. Обновил ответ

Comment: Да, так и сделал за пол минуты до комментария=) Спасибо, вы очень помогли!